# FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "[local]", user "postgres", database "postgres", no encryption

Tags: postgresql

Error:
`FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "[local]", user "postgres", database "postgres", no encryption`

pg_hba.conf:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
```

This is a local testing database. I don't care what or who can connect. I just need to connect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I modified my pg_hba.conf, I idiotically removed the local domain socket line from the pg_hba.conf. Someone from discord helped me fix it.

The fix was to add this line to my pg_hba.conf. Unix only.

```
local   all             all                                     peer
```

Comment: Isn't this against security?